# deployment using jboss cli for domain mode fails to pick modules

Tags: deployment, jboss, ear, wildfly-10, jboss-eap-7

I am using JBoss EAP 7.1 in Domain mode.

I have setup my static modules in `eap_home/modules` folder:

```
com
|- organization
  |- global
    |- main (this has module.xml)
```

I have a `myservice.ear` that I want to deploy.

#### Standalone mode:

Put the *ear* inside `standalone/deployment/` and start the server using `./standalone.sh` : **works fine.**

#### Domain mode:

Deploy using `jboss-cli` : **fails**

```
deploy /<PATH>/myservice.ear --name=myservice --runtime-name=myservice.ear --server-groups=main-server-group
```

I get following error message:

```
[.... /] deploy /<PATH>/myservice.ear --name=myservice --runtime-name=myservice.ear --server-groups=main-server-group
{"WFLYDC0074: Operation failed or was rolled back on all servers. Server failures:" => {"server-group" => {"main-server-group" => {"host" => {"slave1" => {"server-one" => {"WFLYCTL0062: Composite operation failed and was rolled back. Steps that failed:" => {"Operation step-1" => {"WFLYCTL0062: Composite operation failed and was rolled back. Steps that failed:" => {"Operation step-2" => {"WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {"jboss.module.service.\"deployment.services.ear.service-one-SNAPSHOT.war\".main" => "WFLYSRV0179: Failed to load module: deployment.services.ear.service-one-SNAPSHOT.war
    Caused by: org.jboss.modules.ModuleNotFoundException: com.organization.global",.......<few more statements with the same exception> ....
```

Any idea on what could be the reason?

Note: I have modified the file names and messages a little to hide organization specific details. Please let me know if you need any clarification.

#### Extra Info:

The `EAR/META-INF/jboss-deployment-structure.xml` file :

```
<jboss-deployment-structure xmlns="urn:jboss:deployment-structure:1.2" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <deployment>
     <dependencies>
         <module name="com.organization.global" export="true"/>
     </dependencies>
  </deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

I have several WAR files inside the EAR and each of those WAR files contain their own version of `WAR/WEB-INF/jboss-deployment-structure.xml` and contain following:

```
<jboss-deployment-structure xmlns="urn:jboss:deployment-structure:1.0">
  <deployment>
     <dependencies>
        <module name="com.organization.global"/>
     </dependencies>
  </deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

The xml for EAR is inside META-INF but for the WARs, it resides under WEB-INF.

Comment: Does your EAR have a `jboss-deployment-structure.xml`? The modules should work the same for both domain and standalone.

Comment: @JamesR.Perkins Yes, the EAR contains `jboss-deployment-structure.xml` file with following module definition: `<module name="com.organization.global" export="true" />`
I even tried adding `annotations=true` in the module definition tag as suggested by one of the forums, but no luck

Comment: Can you share the contents of the `jboss-deployment-structure.xml`? Do you have the module dependency on both the EAR and the WAR?

Comment: @JamesR.Perkins added content of `jboss-deployment-structure.xml` for both EAR and WAR at the end of question-body.
The EAR contains several WAR files and they all depend on the module.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had set the static modules `com/organization/global` under `EAP_MASTER_HOME/modules/`. 
Deployment in *standalone mode* tries to deploy it only to the server running on master so the deployment works fine.
When I tried to deploy the EAR in domain mode, the server running on slave-eap was looking for the modules under `EAP_SLAVE_HOME/modules/`.

Adding the static modules( or a symbolic link) under `EAP_SLAVE_HOME/modules/` resolved the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Only the `jboss-deployment-structure.xml` from your EAR will be read. If sub-deployments need an additional module dependency you need to add that configuration to the EAR's descriptor.

You should remove the `jboss-deployment-structure.xml` from your WAR and change the one in the EAR to look like the following.

```xml
<jboss-deployment-structure xmlns="urn:jboss:deployment-structure:1.2" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <deployment>
     <dependencies>
         <module name="com.organization.global" export="true"/>
     </dependencies>
  </deployment>
  <sub-deployment name="service-one-SNAPSHOT.war">
     <dependencies>
         <module name="com.organization.global" export="true"/>
     </dependencies>
  </sub-deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

As to why it seems to deploy to a standalone server, that shouldn't be working. Deployments are processed exactly the same. If for it is working I'd say it's likely a bug somewhere.

Comment: Thanks for the help James.. but the issue was with the modules not being copied over to the slave EAP. I had the static modules folder set only in my master EAP and that's why it worked for standanlone mode.